# Disable form submission if it has hyperlink in it

Tags: html, css, forms

I just configured a simple form for a webpage I´m developing (just an input for users mail address of contact and another textarea for their inquiries). Now that is live, I´m getting quite a lot of spam, always coming with a URL in the message. I´m not interested in any real user to enter a hyperlink in their message, so is there a way to avoid the form to be submitted if there is a link in the message with any kind of validation or something like that?

Comment: you can set the conditions and prevent the form submission with the javascript.

Comment: You need to post your HTML and JavaScript as a [mcve]. There are too many aspects of submitting and validating forms.

Answer (score 0):

Spam is likely to be driven programmatically and would bypass any client-side checks you have, so the short answer is:

**Not effectively**.

Handle the check in the server-side code that processes the form submissions instead.

Comment: Finally created some mail rules to manage these kind of emails, permitting only the not suspicious ones. Thanks.